# What does "tout le côté des fois accrochage" mean?

Tags: sens, adverbes, oral, syntaxe

Here is a sentence from the recording of Leçon 27 of *Le nouveau taxi (B1)*. This is the explanation from a psychologist of why some people are addicted to their jobs:

> C'est une grosse recherche en général de reconnaissance professionnelle. Souvent les gens me disent « Oh oui, mais mon employeur est très exigeant ». Et puis **tout le côté des fois accrochage** qu'on peut avoir effectivement au travail **crée** du stress chez... chez les gens... d'où ils ont du mal effectivement à déconnecter hein sur quelques jours seulement de vacances si vous voulez.

I see that the subject of this sentence is *Tout le côté des fois accrochage*. But here *fois* and *accrochage* are both nouns. Why can one put these two nouns consecutively and what does it mean exactly?

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense! It seems to me that it comes from an automatic translator.

Comment: Not only these nouns but other parts of the sentence are also garbage French. That might be a failed voice recognition transcript.

Comment: In your book, who is saying this and are there any indications as to where this person is from?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse I have added the context. Indeed, this is the transcription given in the back of the book.

Comment: @Colescu With the full text, that makes more sense. You initially stripped off the few parts that would have make clear this was a verbatim transcription of what was said instead of well-constructed sentences.

Comment: Et puis **tout le côté** [ *du taxi subit* ] [ **des** | *par*] **fois** [ *un* ] **accrochage** qu'on peut avoir effectivement au travail (en tant que conducteur) **;** [ *cela* ] crée du stress chez …

Comment: @Personne Je pensais que c'était le [taxi](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/44603/2) aussi au départ mais il semble que non « this is the explanation from a psychologist of why some people are addicted to their jobs ». Bof, finalement qui sait.

Comment: Cela change peu de choses : « Et puis tout le côté [des personnes avec lesquelles tu travailles tu subis] *[des|par]fois* [qui amènent un] accrochage (*conflit*) qu'on peut avoir effectivement au travail ; [cela] crée du stress chez …  »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my region (Québec, Canada), [*des fois*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/des_fois) means *parfois* (sometimes) and this has the function of an adverb. Whether it's "sometimes the accrochage" or "sometimes we have that" doesn't make much of a difference in terms of meaning here. The sentence is about *something causing stress in people*. That something is "all that aspect of *sometimes* having an addiction<sup>1</sup> that we may have from work". In either languages that phrasing is a mouthful and imprecise. Indeed [*accrochage*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accrochage) (from the verb *to hook*) also refers people having an argument as well as to a small car accident i.e. fender-bender etc. The sentence doesn't sound very universal to me, seems more of the spoken type, with the speaker refusing to walk back the weird garden path they're leading us on. I'm surprised to find this in a book geared for learners.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I only know we're talking about addiction (to work, workaholic) because of an edit by OP. I'm not used to having the noun *accrochage* refer to addiction even though [*accro*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accro) refers to an addict. This is all because the title of the work refers to *taxi*, *accrochage* has multiple meanings and context makes a difference.</sub>

Comment: Oui, il s'agit peut-être d'une transcription des propos un peu décousus de quequ'un de très stressé et qui a besoin de vacances pour mettre de l'ordre dans tout ça...

Comment: Oui, tout passe mieux quand on a compris qu'il s'agit de français parlé "brut de fonderie" !

Comment: Hahaha _straight pipe_ !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be sure, am I right in thinking that this sentence is not strictly grammatical?

Comment: Welcome. It is grammatical but it's speech which is not very well phrased and I've explored in a follow-up question that choosing _accrochage_ to refer to addiction was not typical. That _des fois_ is an adverb, so there's nothing which would make it ungrammatical in my opinion. It feels like the person is being interviewed or something. If you were writing up a text you wouldn't phrase it like that. That exact bit _tout le côté des fois accrochage_ works but yeah, I would think _parfois la dépendance au travail devient une source de stress_ is much clearer. @Colescu