# L'« accrochage » au travail causant la difficulté à « déconnecter » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, synonymes, travail, antonyme

Dans une [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44600/26366) sur le français parlé on évoque l'*[accrochage](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accrochage) au travail* résultant en une difficulté à *déconnecter*. On réfère probablement à la passion du travail qui peut devenir pathologique.

Est-il courant et usuel d'employer le nom *accrochage* pour désigner le phénomène et autrement comment le désigne-t-on ; est-ce un emploi familier, une extension de sens (*accroche, accrocher, s'accrocher, accrochage*) ; le verbe [*déconnecter*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9connecter) constitue-t-il linguistiquement l'action opposée ou solution correspondante et autrement quel verbe la réalise ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je n'avais jamais lu ou entendu parler d'**accrochage au travail** avec ce sens là<sup>1</sup>, mais, par analogie avec une drogue, souvent rencontré l'expression **être accro au travail** qui explique cet *accrochage*.

Comme substantif, c'est plutôt l'anglicisme **addiction** qui a été largement adopté au moins en France, en concurrence avec le plus irréprochable **dépendance**.

**Décrocher** est courant pour les drogues mais semble un peu radical pour être appliqué au travail. **Déconnecter** est plus approprié car correspondant bien à la déconnexion des outils informatiques liés au travail.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Un accrochage au travail évoque un conflit avec un collègue ou éventuellement de la tôle froissée si le travail en question inclus la conduite de véhicules sur site.</sub>

Comment: Tout ça rend plausible l'hypercorrection erroné du psy. de _addiction_ en suivant le parcours accro, accroc, accrochage ahahahah.

Comment: Oui, un accrochage au travail, c'est une embrouille au boulot. *Accro (à une drogue)* vient bien d'*accroché* même si on ne le dit plus, donc cet *accrochage* n'est pas totalement faux.

Answer (score 0):

En effet, on parle plutôt d'addiction (qui peut amener au surmenage). De manière un peu plus familière ou parlée on peut parler d'être accro au travail comme l'explique bien jiliagre.

Un accrochage au travail pourrait en France avec une signification de mésentente ou mauvais rapport avec un collègue. Avoir un accrochage avec un collègue peut signifier un conflit ponctuel arrivé lors d'un échange, une réunion, etc.